# Unix: Using filename from another file

Tags: unix, awk

A basic Unix question.

I have a script which counts the number of records in a delta file.

```
awk '{ 
    n++ 
  } END {
    if(n >= 1000) print "${completeFile}"; else print "${deltaFile}";
  }' <${deltaFile} >${fileToUse}
```

Then, depending on the IF condition, I want to process the appropriate file:

```
cut -c2-11 < ${fileToUse}
```

But how do I use the contents of the file as the filename itself?
And if there are any tweaks to be made, feel free.

Thanks in advance
Cheers
Simon

Comment: what is `${completeFile}` ?

Comment: `${completeFile}` and `${deltaFile}` are just variable names to the actual files.
The idea is I have a pre-processor comparing this month completeFile with last month completeFile.  The output of that comparison is deltaFile.
Mostly it'll be empty, but if the deltaFile is greater than xx% of the completeFile (the >= 1000 step) then I just want to take the completeFile to the next process via fileToUse ... otherwise I'll take the deltaFile to the next process via fileToUse

Comment: You probably don't need deltaFile, nor most of the steps you're talking about. It might make sense to just have awk compare this month completeFile with last month completeFile and go from there. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (ie. the completeFiIe versions) and expected output so we can help you. This is feeling a lot like an XY question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use as a filename the contents of a file which is itself identified by a variable (as asked)

```
 cut -c2-11 <"$( cat $filetouse )"
 // or in zsh just
 cut -c2-11 <"$( < $filetouse )"
```

unless the filename in the file ends with one or more newline character(s), which people rarely do because it's quite awkward and inconvenient, then something like:

```
read -rdX var <$filetouse; cut -c2-11 < "${var%?}"
// where X is a character that doesn't occur in the filename
// maybe something like $'\x1f'
```

---

Tweaks: your `awk` prints the variable *reference* `${completeFile}` or `${deltaFile}` (because they're within the single-quoted `awk` script) not the value of either variable. If you actually want the value, as I'd expect from your description, you should pass the shell vars to awk vars like this

```
 awk -vf="$completeFile" -vd="$deltaFile" '{n++} END{if(n>=1000)print f; else print d}' <"$deltaFile"`
 # the " around $var can be omitted if the value contains no whitespace and no glob chars
 # people _often_ but not always choose filenames that satisfy this
 # and they must not contain backslash in any case
```

or export the shell vars as env vars (if they aren't already) and access them like

```
 awk '{n++} END{if(n>=1000) print ENVIRON["completeFile"]; else print ENVIRON["deltaFile"]}' <"$deltaFile"
```

Also you don't need your own counter, awk already counts input records

```
 awk -vf=... -vd=... 'END{if(NR>=1000)print f;else print d}' <...
```

or more briefly

```
 awk -vf=... -vd=... 'END{print (NR>=1000?f:d)}' <...
```

or using a file argument instead of redirection so the name is available to the script

```
awk -vf="$completeFile" 'END{print (NR>=1000?f:FILENAME)}' "$deltaFile" # no <
```

and barring trailing newlines as above you don't need an intermediate file at all, just

```
 cut -c2-11 <"$( awk -vf="$completeFile" -'END{print (NR>=1000?f:FILENAME)}' "$deltaFile")"
```

Or you don't really need awk, `wc` can do the counting and any POSIX or classic shell can do the comparison

```
 if [ $(wc -l <"$deltaFile") -ge 1000 ]; then c="$completeFile"; else c="$deltaFile"; fi
 cut -c2-11 <"$c"
```

Comment: A fantastic response ... thank you so much Dave for taking the time to reply so thoroughly.  The key missing piece was from `${fileToUse}` to `"$( cat $fileToUse )"`  which made it function perfectly.  Your additional comments are brilliant and I've incorporated them to streamline the whole statement.  
Thanks again